# Content show/hide with animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created a fiddle. I want to know if I'm doing the right way.

Here is my code,

```
<div class="container">
<div>Sadness is emotional pain associated with, or characterized by feelings of disadvantage, loss, despair, helplessness and sorrow.</div>
<div>Sadness is a common experience in childhood. Acknowledging such emotions can make it easier for families to address more serious emotional problems,[3] although some families may have a (conscious or unconscious) rule that sadness is "not allowed".[4] Robin Skynner has suggested that this may cause problems when "screened-off emotion isn't available to us when we need it... the loss of sadness makes us a bit manic".</div>
<div>Sadness is part of the normal process of the child separating from an early symbiosis with the mother and becoming more independent. Every time a child separates just a tiny bit more, he or she will have to cope with a small loss.</div>
```

**JS:**

```
delay=2000;
function repeat(){
    visibleTextBlock=$('.container div:visible');
    visibleTextBlock.fadeOut();
    visibleTextBlock.next().fadeIn();
} ;
T=setTimeout(function(){
    repeat();
    setTimeout(function(){
        repeat();
    },delay);
},delay);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/y2k58/3/)**

Comment: Where is your javascript/jQuery code? At the minute you're not doing anything.

Comment: I'm doing right way means, what you are doing, how can we say?

Comment: What're you trying to do here?

Comment: You're doing it very *very wrong*, since you appear to not be using any jQuery at all; but yes: you've used JS Fiddle correctly (in that you've produced a valid, albeit incomplete, result/output).

Comment: "I want to know if I'm doing the right way" - Yes, that is the way to create jsfiddle.

Comment: Guys I did miss to add the JavaScript. I did not click on the update button on the fiddle window and copied the link. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

```
delay=2000;

I=setInterval(function(){
    visibleTextBlock=$('.container div:visible');
    visibleTextBlock.fadeOut();
    visibleTextBlock.next().length>0 ? visibleTextBlock.next().fadeIn() : $('.container div:first').fadeIn();
},delay);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ramanmandal2/y2k58/2/.

Comment: @C-link I tried to find out a solution. I hope it works.